# fake model response in backbone.js

Tags: json, backbone.js

How can I fake a REST response in my model s.t. it does not really go to the service but returns a fixed json?

If possible show me a version that does it with overriding sync() and a version that overrides fetch(). I failed with both so this will be a good education for as for the difference between them.

Comment: I don't think you can unless you change sync() method in Backbone source

Comment: the rest service is not ready yet. I do not want to use any mock service or something external to my code. I want to override the backbone method that calls ajax (not override the ajax itself) and instead provide a fixed response

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Backbone.Model.extend({
  fetch: function(){
    var model = this;
    model.set({yourStatic: "Json Here"});
  }
}
```

This should work. From the Backbone documentation:

> `fetch()`:
>   Resets the model's state from the server by delegating to Backbone.sync

Answer (score 2):

If your question is related to unit testing your code without the need for a live API, have a look at [Sinon.JS](http://sinonjs.org). It helps mocking entire API server responses for testing purposes.

Here's an example from the Sinon docs that mocks the $.ajax function of jQuery:

```
{
    setUp: function () {
        sinon.spy(jQuery, "ajax");
    },

    tearDown: function () {
        jQuery.ajax.restore(); // Unwraps the spy
    },

    "test should inspect jQuery.getJSON's usage of jQuery.ajax": function () {
        jQuery.getJSON("/some/resource");

        assert(jQuery.ajax.calledOnce);
        assertEquals("/some/resource", jQuery.ajax.getCall(0).args[0].url);
        assertEquals("json", jQuery.ajax.getCall(0).args[0].dataType);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, my question is not ut related but more for me to get education and try some stuff

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [backbone-faux-server](https://github.com/biril/backbone-faux-server). It will allow you to handle (and 'fake' a response for) *any* sync op (fetch, save, etc) *per* Model (or Collection).

Answer (score 0):

Sinon.js is a good candidate, although if you want to simulate more than a few responses, it might become a lot of work to setup headers, handle write logic, etc.

Building up on Sinon.js, [FakeRest](https://github.com/marmelab/FakeRest) goes a step further and simulates a complete REST API based on a JSON object - all client-side.

Answer (score 0):

My code like that

```
// config
const TEST_JSON = require('./test.json')

const API_MAP = {
    testA: 'someroot'
}
const FAKE_API_MAP = {
    testA: TEST_JSON
}

// here's model
let BaseModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: function() {
        return `${HOST}${API_MAP[this.resourceName]}/`
    }
})
let FakeModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    fetch: function(options) {
        return this.sync('', this, _.extend({}, options));
    },
    sync: function(method, model, options) {
        this.set(FAKE_API_MAP[this.resourceName], this.options)
        this.trigger('sync', this);
    },
});

// now it's easy for switch them 
let modelA = new BaseModel({
    resourceName: 'testA'
})
modelA.fetch()

let fakeModelA = new FakeModel({
    resourceName: 'testA'
})
fakeModelA.fetch()
```